# Having trouble trying to program the shor 9 qubit code

Tags: quantum-circuit, shors-algorithm, programming

I am trying to program in python the following quantum circuit but for some reason when I write the matrix after the z gate, M8, the resultant matrix is zero.
[image]

The code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

qubits = [np.array([[1, 0]]) for i in range(9)]
qubits[0] = np.array([[1, 0]])

Projector = [np.matmul(qubits[i].transpose(), qubits[i]) for i in range(9)]

State_0_projector = np.matmul(np.array([[1, 0]]).transpose(), np.array([[1, 0]]))
State_1_projector = np.matmul(np.array([[0, 1]]).transpose(), np.array([[0, 1]]))

# Gates
Id = np.identity(2)
Id9 = np.identity(9)
X = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0]])
H = np.array([[1, 1], [1, -1]]) / np.sqrt(2)
Z = np.array([[1, 0], [0, -1]])

def kronecker(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I):
    matrix = np.kron(A, np.kron(B, np.kron(C, np.kron(D, np.kron(E, np.kron(F, np.kron(G, np.kron(H, I))))))))
    return matrix

# Initial state
psi = kronecker(qubits[0], qubits[1], qubits[2], qubits[3], qubits[4], qubits[5], qubits[6], qubits[7], qubits[8])


# Encoding of the initial state
M1 = np.add(kronecker(State_0_projector, Id, Id, Id, Id, Id, Id, Id, Id), kronecker(State_1_projector, Id, Id, X, Id, Id, Id, Id, Id))

M2 = np.matmul(np.add(kronecker(State_0_projector, Id, Id, Id, Id, Id, Id, Id, Id),
               kronecker(State_1_projector, Id, Id, Id, Id, Id, X, Id, Id)), M1)

M3 = np.matmul(kronecker(H, Id, Id, H, Id, Id, H, Id, Id), M2)

M4 = np.matmul(np.add(kronecker(State_0_projector, Id, Id, State_0_projector, Id, Id, State_0_projector, Id, Id),
               kronecker(State_1_projector, X, Id, State_1_projector, X, Id, State_1_projector, X, Id)), M3)

M5 = np.matmul(np.add(kronecker(State_0_projector, Id, Id, State_0_projector, Id, Id, State_0_projector, Id, Id),
               kronecker(State_1_projector, Id, X, State_1_projector, Id, X, State_1_projector, Id, X)), M4)

# Error induction on the qubit 0
M6 = np.matmul(kronecker(X, Id, Id, Id, Id, Id, Id, Id, Id), M5)

M7 = np.matmul(kronecker(Z, Id, Id, Id, Id, Id, Id, Id, Id), M6)

# Correction of the flip error
M8 = np.matmul(np.add(kronecker(State_0_projector, Id, Id, State_0_projector, Id, Id, State_0_projector, Id, Id),
               kronecker(State_1_projector, X, Id, State_1_projector, X, Id, State_1_projector, X, Id)), M7)

M9 = np.matmul(np.add(kronecker(State_0_projector, Id, Id, State_0_projector, Id, Id, State_0_projector, Id, Id),
               kronecker(State_1_projector, Id, X, State_1_projector, Id, X, State_1_projector, Id, X)), M8)

M10 = np.matmul(np.add(kronecker(Id, State_0_projector, State_0_projector, Id, State_0_projector, State_0_projector, Id, State_0_projector, State_0_projector),
                kronecker(X, State_1_projector, State_1_projector, X, State_1_projector, State_1_projector, X, State_1_projector, State_1_projector)), M9)


# Correction of the phase error
M11 = np.matmul(kronecker(H, Id, Id, H, Id, Id, H, Id, Id), M10)

M12 = np.matmul(np.add(kronecker(State_0_projector, Id, Id, Id, Id, Id, Id, Id, Id),
                kronecker(State_1_projector, Id, Id, X, Id, Id, Id, Id, Id)), M11)

M13 = np.matmul(np.add(kronecker(State_0_projector, Id, Id, Id, Id, Id, Id, Id, Id),
               kronecker(State_1_projector, Id, Id, Id, Id, Id, X, Id, Id)), M12)


MS = M13


Final_State = np.matmul(MS, psi.transpose())


State_0 = kronecker(np.array([[1, 0]]), qubits[1], qubits[2], qubits[3], qubits[4], qubits[5], qubits[6], qubits[7], qubits[8])
State_1 = kronecker(np.array([[0, 1]]), qubits[1], qubits[2], qubits[3], qubits[4], qubits[5], qubits[6], qubits[7], qubits[8])

Projector_psi_0 = kronecker(State_0_projector, Id, Id, Id, Id, Id, Id, Id, Id)
Projector_psi_1 = kronecker(State_1_projector, Id, Id, Id, Id, Id, Id, Id, Id)


P_0 = (abs(np.matmul(State_0, np.matmul(Projector_psi_0, Final_State))))**2
print(P_0)

P_1 = (abs(np.matmul(State_1, np.matmul(Projector_psi_1, Final_State))))**2
print(P_1)
```

M7 matrix:

[image]

And, well, M8 matrix:

[image]

Each M1, M2, ..., M13 is the matrix of the system defined by the multiplication of the corresponding operator with the previous matrix. I am considering the inicial state being all |0> and the qubit 0 being |1>.

By the way could someone check if the measurement of the qubit 0 in the end of the circuit is currectly done?